# jsoup request returns wrong status code

Tags: java, jsoup

I have a Twitter shortened URL (t.co) and I'm trying to use jsoup to send a request and parse its response. There should be three redirect hops before reaching the final URL. This is not the case when using jsoup, even after setting `followRedirects` to `true`.

My code:

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    try {
        Response response = Jsoup.connect("https://t. co/sLMy6zi4Yw").followRedirects(true).execute(); // Space intentional to avoid SOF shortened errors
        System.out.println(response.statusCode()); // prints 200
    } catch (IOException e) {
        System.out.println(e.getMessage());
    }
}
```

However, using Python's Request library, I can get the right response:

```
response = requests.get('https://t. co/sLMy6zi4Yw', allow_redirects=False)
print(response.status_code)
```

> 301

I'm using jsoup version 1.11.2 and Requests version 2.18.4 with Python 3.5.2.

Anybody have any insight on the matter?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To overcome this special case you can remove the User-Agent header which Jsoup sets by default (for some unknown/undocument reason)

```
    Connection connection = Jsoup.connect(url).followRedirects(true);
    connection.request().removeHeader("User-Agent");
```

Let's examine the raw requests & view the server behavior

Request with user agent (to simulate a browser) returns

- status code 200
- Meta refresh which is a method of instructing a web browser to automatically refresh the current web page or frame after a given time interval, this case 0 seconds and url http://bit. ly/2n3VDpo
- Javascript code which replaces location to the same url (google "meta refresh is depercated" / "drawbacks using meta refresh")

Curl example

```
curl --include --raw "https://t. co/sLMy6zi4Yw" --user-agent "Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/63.0.3239.132 Safari/537.36"
```

Response

> Chrome/63.0.3239.132 Safari/537.36"
>
> HTTP/1.1 200 OK
>
> cache-control: private,max-age=300
>
> content-length: 257
>
> content-security-policy: referrer always;
>
> content-type: text/html; charset=utf-8
>
> referrer-policy: unsafe-url
>
> server: tsa_b
>
> strict-transport-security: max-age=0
>
> vary: Origin
>
> x-response-time: 20
>
> x-xss-protection: 1; mode=block; report=https://twitter.com/i/xss_report
>
> ```
> <head><meta name="referrer" content="always"><noscript><META http-equiv="refresh" content="0;URL=http://bit. ly/2n3VDpo"></noscript><title>http://bit. ly/2n3VDpo</title></head><script>window.opener = null;location.replace("http:\/\/bit. ly\/2n3VDpo")</script>
> ```

Request without user agent returns

- status code 301
- header "location" with the redirect url

Curl example

```
curl --include --raw "https://t. co/sLMy6zi4Yw"
```

> HTTP/1.1 301 Moved Permanently
>
> cache-control: private,max-age=300
>
> content-length: 0
>
> location: http://bit. ly/2n3VDpo
>
> server: tsa_b
>
> strict-transport-security: max-age=0
>
> vary: Origin
>
> x-response-time: 9